# How to get the numeric vector if I know the value of that vector in R

Tags: r

So, I will give an example.
w=5
now some function, say "inverse"...
What I want is this

> inverse(5)

The output should be "w".

I wanted to ask whether there is any inbuilt function for this in R.

If not then how to write a code for this?

Comment: Huh? Is `w` a variable? If so, is it the only variable equal to 5? Or how does `inverse` know w=5?

Comment: This sounds like an awful idea. When working with R, you should minimize the number of variables you have floating around in the global environment. It sounds like w should be part of a list.

Comment: I can make sure that it is the only variable equal to 5.

Comment: The really important question here is:  what problem are you trying to solve?  If you are truly searching your environment for any possible matches, you are seriously misunderstanding how to use `R` -- or any language for that matter.   As @SeñorO says, you should put all the variables that are of interest into a single list.

Comment: See what I am trying to code is this:                                                                  So, I want plot a graph of efficiency (i.e. the

Comment: I am writing a code for a model for the distribution of the species ina community acc to their relative abundances.

Comment: So in that I have created a data which represents that community satisfying that particular model. Now, after that I simply selected some individuals (some sample size) & I am trying to replot the graph of relative abundances versus rank of the species.

Comment: So, I might not get all the species present in the community. So, I am plotting a graph of efficiency (i.e. the ratio of number of species got from the sample collection to the actual number of species present) versus 1. Sample size 2. number of species in the community 3. number of times the data is collected...

Comment: So, while writing this function, if my input for , say, "sample size" is "zero" then my X-axis will be "sample size" for the efficiency graph. So, for that I need to know whose value is "zero". That is why I require the programme.

Comment: I think we still have insufficient info on your problem.. What is the type of object the data is stored in? Is it a list, a data.frame, etc.?

Comment: It is a vector of numbers.

Comment: If `x` is a vector of numbers and you are looking for all the indexes at which a value of, say, `5` occurs, call `which(x == 5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite an interesting problem, IMHO (at least in theory - I don't recommend doing anything like this in *real* applications).

Let's bind some names in the global environment (you may conceive it as creating "variables" in "the console"):

```
x <- 1:3
y <- c(1, 2, 3)
z <- list("a")
w <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here is a function that searches thru each name in the global environment and checks whether any object bound to that name is *identical* with given `value`:

```
inverse <- function(value) {
   objects <- ls(envir=globalenv())
   for (o in objects)
      if (identical(get(o, envir=globalenv()), value))
         return(o)
   return(NULL) # if not found
}
```

Some results:

```
inverse(1:3)
## [1] "x"
inverse(c(1, 2, 3))
## [1] "y"
inverse(list("a"))
## [1] "z"
inverse(1:4) # no such object, as w is not identical to c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
## NULL
```

The test performed by `identical` may be too strict, but I think it's a nice starting point for your experiments.

Comment: What if you have another variable with the same value? This only returns the first one found.

Comment: @Thomas good point, but the upgrades to this answer should be left as an exercise to the reader :-)